# Autocompletion with Indentation not working in AvalonEdit

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock, avalonedit

I am to new to avalonEdit and using it for my custom language, the lanuguage does not use { } for block, instead it uses some keyword use as end. So i tried to implement feature that will automatically complete block for user and indent cursor, now the completion is working but indentation not working.

When user type in

```
function name()
```

and press enter i want to have

```
function name()
    |
end function
```

instead i am getting

```
function name()
|
end function
```

| representing cursor

Below is implementation the insertion working perfectly

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit;
using ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Document;

public class AutocompleteHandler
{
    private TextEditor editor;
    private const string TriggerWord = "function";
    private const string ClosingBlock = "end function";

    public AutocompleteHandler(TextEditor editor)
    {
        this.editor = editor;
        this.editor.TextArea.PreviewKeyDown += TextArea_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

   
    private void TextArea_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            int currentOffset = editor.CaretOffset;
            TextDocument document = editor.Document;

            // Get the current line
            DocumentLine currentLine = document.GetLineByOffset(currentOffset);
            int lineOffset = currentLine.Offset;
            string lineText = document.GetText(currentLine);

            // Check if the line contains the trigger word followed by a valid function declaration
            if (IsValidFunctionDeclaration(lineText))
            {
                // Insert the closing block
                string indentation = GetLineIndentation(lineText);
                string closingBlockText = $"{indentation}{ClosingBlock}";

                // Update the content of the text in the editor
                
                document.Insert(currentOffset,  $"\n\n{closingBlockText}");


                // Adjust cursor position
                int cursorLine = currentLine.LineNumber + 1; // Line number of the inserted closing block
                int cursorColumn = indentation.Length + 4; // Cursor column position in the middle of the block
               
                editor.TextArea.Caret.Line = cursorLine;
                editor.TextArea.Caret.Column = cursorColumn;
                editor.TextArea.Caret.BringCaretToView();

                // Mark the event as handled
                e.Handled = true;
            }   
        }
    }




    private bool IsValidFunctionDeclaration(string lineText)
    {
        // Remove leading and trailing whitespaces
        lineText = lineText.Trim();

        // Check if the line starts with the trigger word "function"
        if (!lineText.StartsWith(TriggerWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return false;

        // Check if the line ends with either an empty parameter list "()"
        // or a parameter list with at least one character inside
        return lineText.EndsWith("()") || lineText.EndsWith(")");
    }

    private string GetLineIndentation(string lineText)
    {
        int indentationLength = lineText.TakeWhile(char.IsWhiteSpace).Count();
        return lineText.Substring(0, indentationLength);
    }

}
```